# HTML export on EPPlus?

Tags: html, .net, export, export-to-excel, epplus

Had a quick question about the EPPlus library.  Can it export an excel spreadsheet as an HTML page?  The application I am writing needs to be able to do this.

Comment: Do you need to export just tabular data in html format or the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Spire.XLS** which enables developers to convert Excel to other popular formats, such as PDF, XML, HTML, CSV, Image format etc

Its @ Nuget, **Install-Package Spire.XLS -Version 8.4.13**

Comment: I have never used Nuget.  Is there a dll I can download? Or do I need to install a Nuget utility to get the code and compile it?

Comment: Be careful, It's a trap!

Answer (score 0):

You could extract datatable from excel file using EPPlus and convert it to HTML using the code described here:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/export-datatable-to-html-in-C-Sharp/

Afterwards, you can export the html string to excel file as:

```
private void ExportToXLS(string data)
{
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                                               "attachment;filename=Your_File_Name.xls");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        EnableViewState = false;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  There is a lot of formatting I would need to add to this code.  My data tables have a lot of coloring in them.

Answer (score 0):

EPPlus 6, released April 2022, has support for exporting ranges and tables to html with separate css. See these samples https://samples.epplussoftware.com/HtmlExport/